# Mid Function cuts off leading 0

Tags: excel

I'm using the Mid() to extract information from an Oracle dump and when I try to extract a number that has a leading 0, excel automatically cuts it off. Is there a way to keep the 0?

Example in cell 6,1 = "0030645"

```
Sub snip4()

Dim text As String

text = Cells(6, 1).Value
Cells(7, 4) = Mid(text, 4, 4)
End Sub
```

Output to 7,4 ="645"

Desired output = "**0645**"

Cell is dumped as a General format

Comment: How about making 7,4 as Text?

Comment: `Cell is dumped as a General format` - then dump it as text format.

Comment: Tried it before I posted, doesn't fix the issue. love the quick wit though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could **change cell format** to "Text":

```
Sub snip4()
    Dim text As String

    text = Cells(6, 1).Value
    With Cells(7, 4)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Mid(text, 4, 4)
    End With
End Sub
```

or another option - use **prefix character**:

```
Sub snip4()
    Dim text As String

    text = Cells(6, 1).Value
    Cells(7, 4) = "'" & Mid(text, 4, 4)
End Sub
```

Comment: Both worked, thanks! The first seems to change the format to text before pasting. Can you explain how the 2nd works?

Comment: try to select your `Cells(7, 4)` in worksheet and look at formula bar - there is `'` sign before text. It is a special character that tells excel that this value should be stored as text without convertation to any other format. Hope it's clear:)